# listen for a click outside a cell if this is in edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and I listen for double click on a table cell. If user double click on a cell that cell becomes editable. I am looking for how to revert the "edit" state once the user clicks outside the cell (anywhere else on the page).
The code I have so far is working for entering the "edit" mode:

```
$('table tbody tr td').dblclick(function(){
    var cell=$(this)
    var value=cell.text();
    var rowIndex = cell.parent().index('table tbody tr');
    var tdIndex = cell.index('table tbody tr:eq('+rowIndex+') td');
    //my logic on editing
    //the event handling if I click outside of that `cell`
});
```

The code I miss should be triggered only if there is a cell being edited, shouldn't interfere with other click events on the page. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: you could listen to a click event on the window object and first check if there is an active editable cell. If there is then proceed to check the element that was clicked if the element isn't the active cell (editable cell) then you switch the active cells state back to default (read only mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach a `click` event listener to the document that checks whether one of the table cells contains the event target. If not, you know the `click` event was not directed towards the table cell, and you can perform the logic to disable editing:

```js
const tableCells = $('table tbody tr td')
tableCells.dblclick(function() {
  $(this).attr('contenteditable', 'true').focus();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  if (!tableCells.toArray().some(f => f.contains(e.target))) {
    tableCells.removeAttr('contenteditable');
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>World!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Beautiful :> :)

Comment: thanks, make sense to me! the `(!tableCells.toArray().some(f => f.contains(e.target)))` is outside my actual knowledge so thanks for teaching me something new! My only question is how big a table can be to have a performance issue to put each cell in a constant

Comment: @LelioFaieta A table with 1000 or so cells shouldn't be a problem for the client's browser.